# Sliding window solution for min length substring with all distinct characters of the original string

Tags: java, string, algorithm

Could anyone please tell where am I going wrong. Below is my code.
Here I am using sliding window solution with left and right as pointers to String.
"dist_count" contains the count for unique characters in string.

```
public class Solution {
    public String findSubstring(String s) {
        if (s == null || s.length() == 0)
            return "";
        int dist_count = 0;
        int[] hash = new int[256]; // character hash
        boolean[] visited = new boolean[256];
        // record each character in s to hash
        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            hash[c]++;
        }
        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            if (visited[c] == false) {
                dist_count++;
                visited[c] = true;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(dist_count);
        int left = 0, right = 0, count = 0;
        int min_window = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int startIndex = -1;
        while (right < s.length()) {
            if (hash[s.charAt(right)] >= 1) {
                count++;
            }
            hash[s.charAt(right)]--;
            right++;

            if (count == dist_count) {
                while (hash[s.charAt(left)] > 1) {
                    if (hash[s.charAt(left)] > 1)
                        hash[s.charAt(left)]--;
                    left++;
                }
                int window = right - left + 1;
                if (min_window > window) {
                    min_window = window;
                    startIndex = left;
                }
            }
        }
        return s.substring(startIndex, startIndex + min_window);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Solution ob = new Solution();
        String str = ob.findSubstring("abdacbfcabegbdfcadcefa");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your current result? What result do you expect?

Comment: I expect a minimum-length substring which contains all the distinct characters present in the original substring.
Example: str = aaaabcadbgbbacbdaaaag
output = abcadbg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is right but there are some issues in implementation.
You should not use the hash leftover from original string. Look at the following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) hash[i] = 0;  // Before entering while reset hash
                                           // counters for sliding window
while (right < s.length()) {
    if (hash[s.charAt(right)] == 0) {  // Use hash here for counting frequency
        count++;
}
hash[s.charAt(right)]--;  // Consistently increment for right and decrement for left
```

[Working code](https://ideone.com/BVOV4K) with above changes

Comment: With these changes, the output for "abdacbfcabegbdfcadcefa" would be "abdacbfcabegb", however it should be "abdacbfcabeg".